# Cannot write uploaded image to file

Tags: image, perl

I'm trying to save an animated gif to a file location. Here is my current code:

```
# create folder location and file path name
my $dn="cmp".int(rand(10));
my $fn="ca".int(rand(10)).int(rand(10)).int(rand(10)).int(rand(10)).int(rand(10)).int(rand(10)).".gif";
while (-f "$datapath/$dn/$fn") { $fn="ca".int(rand(10)).int(rand(10)).int(rand(10)).int(rand(10)).int(rand(10)).int(rand(10)).".gif"; }

# open the uploaded image for saving to a file
open (IMAGE,$insfn{'attachment'});
binmode(IMAGE);

# open the file path for writing the image to
open (OUTPUT,"$datapath/$dn/$fn");
binmode(OUTPUT);

# write the image to the file
my $buf;
my $bufSize=4096;
while(read(IMAGE,$buf,$bufSize)) { print OUTPUT $buf; }
```

For some reason its not saving the image to the file.

Not sure what to do past this point Im fairly new to perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't opened OUTPUT for writing.

replace

```
open (OUTPUT,"$datapath/$dn/$fn");
```

with

```
open (OUTPUT, ">", "$datapath/$dn/$fn");
```

and Perl will create the file, truncate it if it exists already, and allow writes to it.

[Relevant documentation.](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)